# Conformal map but not analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Is there an example of a conformal map(which preserves angles with orientation) which is not analytic defined on any open subset of complex plane?

Answer (score 3):

No. The two concepts are equivalent for functions whose derivative never vanishes.

Comment: Actually, they are not equivalent, for instance, conformal maps are usually required to have nonvanishing derivative, but indeed, every conformal map is analytic.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Quite right! I've edited my answer.

Comment: My question is: is there a conformal map which is not "an analytic function with nonzero derivative"? If a conformal map is analytic then it has to have nonzero derivative. So my question is: Is there a conformal map which is not analytic?

Comment: @KGowriNavada I don't know right now where to find a proof, but Peter J. Olver says it [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/ln_/cml.pdf); see the remark after theorem 5.12. So, the answer to your question from the latest comment is negative.

Comment: @KGowriNavada: This theorem will be in most textbooks on complex analysis (it is essentially a linear algebra exercise). Which book are you using?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Inedd. If I had my library at hand right now, I would have already provided an answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what if function has non zero derivative at some point z.(but not differentiable in nbhd of that z .i.e not analytic).

Answer (score 1):

Conformality (and orientation preservation) will allow you to construct a complex derivative (as in "linear approximation") at each point, and complex differentiable functions are holomorphic, which implies analytic. Not that any of what I've said here is trivial (and there might be caveats that I'm forgetting), but it's how I thought your question is most naturally answered.

Comment: Are you saying conformal if and only if analytic with nonzero derivative? I have seen a proof when the conformal function has continuous first order partial derivatives then it has a nonzero derivative at a point (Ahlfors) But that does not answer my question

Comment: Are you saying conformal is equivalent to being analytic and having a nonzero derivative?

Comment: If you believe everything I say in my answer, then this answers your question as it stands: You asked "is there a conformal map which isn't analytic?", and my answer tells you exactly that conformal implies analytic, so the answer is "no". If you have the additional question "does analytic with non-zero derivative imply conformal?", then my answer is "yes, it does".

Answer (score 0):

You say "which preserves angles with orientation": it would be better to say "which preserves angles with orientation between any two curves" or equivalently "**whose differential** preserves angle with orientation, not necessarily the map itself"). Among other thing this implies that conformal maps must be at least $\mathbb{R}$-differentiable.

"Complex analytic" in an open set means $\mathbb{R}-$differentiable in that open set **and** with the differential being representable multiplicatively by a complex scalar, that is, the differential being a $\mathbb{C}$-linear application, that is, the differential being a $\mathbb{R}$-linear application **that** transforms the tangent vector at any point of every curve into a vector whose length and angle are incremented w.r.t. to the tangent vector by a *non-negative* factor and an additive quantity respectively that are dependent only by the point and not by the tangent vector.

"Conformal" means **$\mathbb{R}$-differentiable** and such that the oriented angle between the vectors into which its differential transforms the tangent vectors of any two curves at their intersection point is the same of those tangent vectors.

You can now see that begin complex analytic implies being conformal only if in the above "complex analytic" description *non-negative* is specialized in *positive* (that means non-null differential), else you cound not even measure the angle if one or both of the two transformed vectors has a zero length.

But it is also that conformal implies complex analytic, because if the factor of the length increment operated by an operator on a tangent vector depends on the tangent vector itself, while at the same time the additional amount for the angle does not depend on the tanget vector, then this operator is not a $\mathbb{R}$-linear operator and consequently not a differential.